# how to set socket.io origins to restrict connections to one url

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

We have one html site and one node.js server which serves that website.
The website and the server exchange data using socke.io.
We found this in the documentation:

*origins defaults to* `*:*`
    *The origins that are allowed to connect to the Socket.IO server.*

Our html.site is on `http://questionexample.com/page1` .
Only this site may connect to our server.(But everyone may connect to that website.)
How do we have to set the origins?

Answer (score 43):

If you dig into Socket.io source code, you will find such lines:

```
var origin = request.headers.origin || request.headers.referer
  , origins = this.get('origins');

...

var parts = url.parse(origin);
parts.port = parts.port || 80;
var ok =
  ~origins.indexOf(parts.hostname + ':' + parts.port) ||
  ~origins.indexOf(parts.hostname + ':*') ||
  ~origins.indexOf('*:' + parts.port);
```

As you can see Socket.io takes origin (or referer) that came from the client, retrieves domain name and port,
and compares with the `origins` option you specified.

**So the valid `origins` values are (`*` means "any"):**

- `testsite.com:80`
- `http://testsite.com:80`
- `http://*:8080`
- `*:8080`
- `testsite.com:* http://someotherdomain.com:8080` *(multiple origins separated by space)*
- `testsite.com:*/somepath` *(socket.io will ignore /somepath)*
- `*:*`

And these are invalid (because no port number):

- `testsite.com`
- `http://testsite.com`
- `http://testsite.com/somepath`

Also note that if you specify `sub.testsite.com` as origins value, the `testsite.com` will be **valid** origin.

Answer (score 9):

I've had similar problem. 
Try run node in production mode `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`. 
I had that code ([as recommended here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#recommended-production-settings)):

```
io.configure('production', function(){
    console.log("Server in production mode");
    io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
    io.enable('browser client etag'); // apply etag caching logic based on version number
    io.enable('browser client gzip'); // the file
    io.set('log level', 1);           // logging
    io.set('transports', [            // all transports (optional if you want flashsocket)
        'websocket'
        , 'flashsocket'
        , 'htmlfile'
        , 'xhr-polling'
        , 'jsonp-polling'
    ]);
io.set('origins', 'http://questionexample.com/page1:*');
});
```

and Node rans in development mode so it simply couldn't work. After enabling production mode everything is ok.

I know that it is a little bit late answer but maybe someone else will use that

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of `socket.io` (up to the current `4.x.x` you need to set CORS origin as part of the server options.

CORS is now split off into its own module - See the [readme](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options) for details.

The default config is;

```
{
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
```

and to restrict to one site with any subdomain use;

```
cors: {
        origin: [/\.example\.com$/],
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
        }
```

Here is a very simple/basic config block for those who come looking without using express or anything other than the raw socket.io engine;
Edit: Updated for version 3 of `socket.io`.

```
// Options for socket.io => 3.0.0
var options = {
        allowUpgrades: true,
        transports: [ 'polling', 'websocket' ],
        pingTimeout: 9000,
        pingInterval: 3000,
        cookie: 'mycookie',
        httpCompression: true,
        cors: '*:*' <---- Allow any origin here [NOTE THE NAME CHANGE]
};
```

Older versions use;

```
// Options for socket.io > 1.0.0
var options = {
        allowUpgrades: true,
        transports: [ 'polling', 'websocket' ],
        pingTimeout: 9000,
        pingInterval: 3000,
        cookie: 'mycookie',
        httpCompression: true,
        origins: '*:*' <---- Allow any origin here
};

io = require('socket.io')(8010, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on server side with url of your site

```
  if (origin !== 'https://foo.example.com') {
    return callback('origin not allowed', false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think `io.set('origins', http://questionexample.com/page1)` should do it

Comment: thx for your answer, but this doesn't work for us. We get the following warning: _illegal origin_ when we load the website and it doesn't connect.

Comment: what are you trying to accive? I think origin is the ip of the client. For security the origin limitation, that you suggested isn't working either, because the url could be changed easily. You may want to have a look a [Authorisation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing) for the client.

Comment: You need a port number too

Comment: io.set is no longer supported in the latest releases. config goes on the server like var socket = require('socket.io')({
  // options go here
});

Comment: change to `io.origins(['https://foo.example.com:443']);`

or

`io.origins((origin, callback) => {
  if (origin !== 'https://foo.example.com') {
    return callback('origin not allowed', false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
});`

see: [new-Server-httpServer-options](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#new-Server-httpServer-options)