# Socket.io + Node.js Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, cors

I'm using node and socket.io to write a chat application. It works fine on Chrome but mozilla gives an error to enable the Cross-Origin Requests.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://waleedahmad.kd.io:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401964309289-2&sid=1OyDavRDf4WErI-VAAAI. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Here's my code to start node server.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(), 
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    path = require('path');
server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

On the client side.

```
var socket = io.connect('//waleedahmad.kd.io:3000/');
```

Script tag on HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//waleedahmad.kd.io:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I'm also using .htaccess file in the app root directory. (waleedahmad.kd.io/node).

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so, what was your solution?

Answer (score 292):

## Simple Server-Side Fix

❗ DO NOT USE "socketio" package... use "socket.io" instead. "socketio" is out of date. Some users seem to be using the wrong package.

❗ SECURITY WARNING: Setting origin `*` opens up the ability for phishing sites to imitate the look and feel of your site and then have it work just the same while grifting user info. If you set the origin, you can make their job harder, not easier. Also looking into using a [CSRF token](https://www.synopsys.com/glossary/what-is-csrf.html#:%7E:text=Cross%2DSite%20Request%20Forgery%20(CSRF)%20is%20an%20attack%20that,has%20in%20an%20authenticated%20user.) as well would be a great idea.

**socket.io v3**

docs: https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

cors options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});
```

**socket.io < v3**

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});
```

or

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

or

```
io.origins('*:*') // for latest version
```

`*` alone doesn't work which took me down rabbit holes.

Comment: I am using latest version and it is not,, its giving me connection refused error

Comment: @gamer maybe work through all the first principles then going up, for example, is my firewall blocking the port? Can I ping my server etc etc.

Comment: You are a genius. This is the best solution with express!

Comment: From v3.x, please refer to this ( https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/ ) and this ( https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options ) links.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    'cors': {
        'methods': ['GET', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT'],
        'origin': true// accept from any domain
    }
});
```

Comment: @vee Excellent solution!

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. it saved the day.,      const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

Comment: The first one worked, the others gave me an error

Comment: I tried socket.io 4.1.2 on my nodejs server. But it always remain the same problem.What i have to do?

Comment: you could use: https://codesandbox.io/ and setup node sandbox... invite people in to edit, i do that myself sometimes, i can take a look if you do that, otherwise, can't see your code

Comment: socket.io v4.4.1  only first option working adding `cors: { origin : '*',}}` fixed the problem

Comment: @King Friday is that possible to emit particular room at cross domain like                                      io.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only'); //sending to individual socketid

Answer (score 63):

I am using `v2.1.0` and none of the above answers worked for me. 
This did though:

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const sio = require("socket.io")(server, {
    handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
        const headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin, //or the specific origin you want to give access to,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        };
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        res.end();
    }
});

sio.on("connection", () => {
    console.log("Connected!");
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I wish to understand why does this works over io.origin("*:*")

Makes no sense, I even tried to override this with origin handlers from socket.io, noting worked except this..

I'm using socket.io 1.7.4 and socket.io-client 2.2.0 with socket.io-adapter-mongodb 0.0.2

Comment: I'm so grateful I found this post, I spent 5-6 hours today to try to enable CORS on my socket-server. I literally tried every single method I could find on stackoverflow. This is the only method that worked for me. I don't understaand why io.origin(":"), did not work in this case either. I've built other socket servers in the past and never encountered problems. If someone has a theory I would love to hear it. Anyways many thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 36):

You can try to set `origins` option on the server side to allow cross-origin requests:

```
io.set('origins', 'http://yourdomain.com:80');
```

Here `http://yourdomain.com:80` is the origin you want to allow requests from.

You can read more about `origins` format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711242/2600208)

Answer (score 28):

For anyone looking here for new Socket.io (3.x) the [migration documents](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#CORS-handling) are fairly helpful.

**In particular this snippet:**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Comment: perfect! Now my socket breaks at for POST request's saying it's a bad handshake from my vue socket.io client. But I see this new error as progress. Thank you so much!

Comment: Man, I wasted 1 week trying, searching and studying the documentation.
And I resolved the problem.

I will share with you a couple of secrets:

1) The solution depends on the socket.io version (check your package.json) and SELECT SAME VERSION on the documentation site!!!!!!
2) Whatch out for the exceptions on the documentation. On my case, "...cors: {origin: "*"}..." did not work because the connection requires credentials. So, when you activate credentials, you must declare origin as a function (inside cors)

origin: (_req, callback) => {
 callback(null, true);
},

Answer (score 14):

If you are getting `io.set not a function` or `io.origins not a function`, you can try such notation:

```
import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
```

Answer (score 11):

I tried above and nothing worked for me. Following code is from [socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-origins-fn) and it worked.

```
io.origins((origin, callback) => {
  if (origin !== 'https://foo.example.com') {
      return callback('origin not allowed', false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

client:

```js
const socket = io('https://sms-server.cedrick1227.repl.co/', { });
```

server:

```
const io = new socket.Server(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
```

it works like a charm for me.

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation? What does your code do and how does it help the OP?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Normaly I'm using `handlePreflightRequest` config value for solving this problem in old versions but in new version (4.4.0) this answer is perfectly working. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I'm using an HTTP server and socket.io

**Error:**

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

**Solution:**

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http,  { cors: { origin: '*' } });
```

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to say that after trying a bunch of things, what fixed my CORS problem was simply using an older version of socket.io (version 2.2.0). My package.json file now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "current-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0"
  }
}
```

If you execute `npm install` with this, you may find that the CORS problem goes away when trying to use socket.io. At least it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks bro, none of the answers worked from various sites except downgrading the socket.io version :-( It wasted lots of time. Thank you very much. Finally, it's working with ^2.2.0

Answer (score 5):

I was also struggling with this issue until i saw Documentation says: "You can't set 'withCredentials' to true with origin: *, you need to use a specific origin:". So my code looks like this, hope is useful:

WEB CLIENT

```
const { io } = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("localhost:3000", {
  extraHeaders: {
    "my-custom-header": "abcd"
  }
});
```

SERVER

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use following on the server side:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
 
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
 
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
 
socket.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("socket connection : ", socket.id);
});
 
server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("server has started!");
});
```

Comment: This is what the docs say, but it is not working for me either. SocketIO behaves like no cors settings were given.

Comment: Today it works :-| Backing my suspicion that the whole CORS method is in fact based on black magic.

Comment: I did origin: "\*.\*" from server side on looking at some other fixes, changing it to origin: "*" worked for me. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

After read a lot of subjetcs on StakOverflow and other forums, I found the working solution for me. This solution is for working **without Express**.

here are the prerequisites.

- call your js script (src=) form the same server the socket will be connected to (not CDN or local call)
- ensure to have the same version of socket.io on server and client side
- node modules required : [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html), [socket.io](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js) and [winston for logging](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)
- Install Let's encrypt certbot and [generate certificate for your domain](https://itnext.io/node-express-letsencrypt-generate-a-free-ssl-certificate-and-run-an-https-server-in-5-minutes-a730fbe528ca) or buy a SSL certificate
- jQuery declared before [socket.io.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js) on client side
- UTF-8 encoding

---

**SERVER SIDE**

```
// DEPENDENCIES
var fs       = require('fs'),
    winston  = require('winston'),
    path     = require('path');


// LOGS
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level     : 'info',
    format    : winston.format.json(),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({ level: 'debug' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'err.log', level: 'err' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
    ]
});


// CONSTANTS
const Port          = 9000,
      certsPath     = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/';


// STARTING HTTPS SERVER 
var server = require('https').createServer({
    key:                fs.readFileSync(certsPath + 'privkey.pem'), 
    cert:               fs.readFileSync(certsPath + 'cert.pem'), 
    ca:                 fs.readFileSync(certsPath + 'chain.pem'), 
    requestCert:        false, 
    rejectUnauthorized: false 
},
(req, res) => {

    var filePath = '.' + req.url;
    logger.info('FILE ASKED : ' + filePath);

    // Default page for visitor calling directly URL
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';

    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;      
        case '.jpg':
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            break;
        case '.wav':
            contentType = 'audio/wav';
            break;
    }

    var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, // 30 days
        'Content-Type': contentType
    };

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            if(err.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./errpages/404.html', function(err, content) {
                    res.writeHead(404, headers);
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                fs.readFile('./errpages/500.html', function(err, content) {
                    res.writeHead(500, headers);
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(200, headers);
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.writeHead(204, headers);
        res.end();
    }

}).listen(port); 


//OPENING SOCKET
var io = require('socket.io')(server).on('connection', function(s) {

    logger.info("SERVER > Socket opened from client");

    //... your code here

});
```

---

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
<script src="https://my.domain.com:port/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.socket = io.connect('https://my.domain.com:port', {
            secure: true // for SSL
        });

        //... your code here

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is one of the clearest example of a bare-bone NodeJS server with socket.io integration; upvoted

Answer (score 4):

Alright I had some issues getting this to work using a self signed cert for testing so I am going to copy my setup that worked for me. If your not using a self signed cert you probably wont have these issues, hopefully!

To start off depending on your browser Firefox or Chrome you may have different issues and I'll explain in a minute.

First the Setup:

**Client**

```
// May need to load the client script from a Absolute Path
<script src="https://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/node/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
          rememberUpgrade:true,
          transports: ['websocket'],
          secure:true, 
          rejectUnauthorized: false
              }
var socket = io.connect('https://www.YOURDOMAIN.com:PORT', options);

// Rest of your code here
</script>
```

**Server**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/file.crt'),

};
var origins = 'https://www.YOURDOMAIN.com:*';
var app = require('https').createServer(options,function(req,res){

    // Set CORS headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.YOURDOMAIN.com:*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if ( req.method === 'OPTIONS' || req.method === 'GET' ) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        return;
            }

});

var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(PORT);
```

For development the options used on the client side are ok in production you would want the option:

```
 rejectUnauthorized: false
```

You would more than likely want set to "true"

Next thing is if its a self signed cert you will need to vist your server in a separate page/tab and accept the cert or import it into your browser.

For Firefox I kept getting the error

```
MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

The solution for me was to add the following options and accepting the cert in a different page/tab.

```
{ 
rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

In Chrome I had to open another page and accept the cert but after that everything worked fine with out having to add any options.

Hope this helps.

References:

https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/issues/259

https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#methods

Answer (score 3):

This could be a certification issue with Firefox, not necessarily anything wrong with your CORS. [Firefox CORS request giving 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' despite headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cors-request-giving-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers)

I was running into the same exact issue with Socketio and Nodejs throwing CORS error in Firefox. I had Certs for *.myNodeSite.com, but I was referencing the LAN IP address 192.168.1.10 for Nodejs. (WAN IP address might throw the same error as well.) Since the Cert didn't match the IP address reference, Firefox threw that error.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing problem while making an chat app using socket.io and node.js & React. Also this issue is not spacefic to Firefox browser, i face same issue in Edge & Chrome also.

> "Cross-Origin request is blocked and it is used by some other resources..."

Then i download cors in project directory and put it in the server file index.js as below: To download simply type command using node.js :

> npm install cors

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

This will allow CORS to used by different resources in the files and allow cross origin request in the browser.

Comment: Same issue occurs after implementation. Works in localhost but not outside

Answer (score 3):

### **For those using `socket.io` >= v4.4.0**

Because I wanted needed the CORS option only for local development, nothing worked here for me.

The solution that I implemented, backend-side :

```js
    const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
        path: '/api/socket.io',
    });

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        io.engine.on('initial_headers', (headers, req) => {
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000';
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = true;
        });

        io.engine.on('headers', (headers, req) => {
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000';
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = true;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['https://example.com','http://example.com','ip-address'],
    }
});
```

Dont use **origin: '*'** it is a *big **security** mistake*!

**origin** can be used like an array with diffrent entry types:

- URI with protocols like http/https
- IP Address
- Environment variables like process.env.WEB_URL

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:
[Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292478/socket-io-cors-blocked/65069469#65069469)

**Server:**

```
let exp = require('express');
let app = exp();

//UPDATE: this is seems to be deprecated
//let io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(9009));
//New Syntax:
const io = require('socket.io')(app.listen(9009));

app.all('/', function (request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});
```

**Client:**

```
<!--LOAD THIS SCRIPT FROM SOMEWHERE-->
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:9009/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io("127.0.0.1:9009/", {
        "force new connection": true,
        "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
        "timeout": 10001, 
        "transports": ["websocket"]
        }
    );
</script>
```

*I remember this from the combination of stackoverflow answers many days ago; but I could not find the main links to mention them*

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution from the official documentation:

> [Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/)

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {cors: {
origin: "https://example.com", // or "*"
methods: ["GET", "POST"]}});
```

Comment: This has fixed my issue, I was trying to connect the socket from the `Angular` app and using `ngx-socket-io` module in the Angular app.

Answer (score 2):

The combination that works for me is:

```
socketio = require('socket.io')(http, {
  origins: process.env.WEB_URL, // http(s)://...
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.WEB_URL,
    credentials: true
  }
}).listen(process.env.SOCKET_PORT) // 8899

app.set('socketio', socketio)
```

Answer (score 1):

i simply updated the version of socket.io from 2.x.x to 4.1.2 for backend and did the same ie. updated the version of socket.io-client at frontend from 2.x.x to 4.1.2 ....And it worked

Comment: I did not want this to work for me but sadly it did. After hours of debugging :(. So thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So, basically in v2, the Socket.IO server automatically added the necessary headers to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) therefor there was no problem for connection between client and server. But this behavior, while convenient, was not great in terms of security, because it meant that all domains were allowed to reach your Socket.IO server.

In v3 and above versions the CORS is disabled by default. Therefor you need to explicitly enable them on your server side script.

Example of my code:

In v2 of socket.io the server script looked like :

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000);
```

But in v3 and above versions this code becomes to :

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000, {
    cors: {
            origin: ['http://localhost:5500'],
     },
  });
```

// Remember by setting cors you allow you client to communicate with the  socket server

// In this case 8000 is my port on which my socket connection is running and 5500 is my port where my client files are hosted.

**// Socket connection runs on a different port and your client files on different**

// Also you need to install `socket.io-client` where you have installed your socket.io modules

For more clarification I'm adding my files

This is my HTML File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"" content="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascript/client.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Chat App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my javascript/client.js

`const socket = io('http://localhost:8000/');`

And this is server/server.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000, {
  cors: {
   origin: ['http://localhost:5500'],
   },
 });

io.on('connection', socket =>{
  console.log(socket.id);
 });
```

// If you still can't get it more detailed information can be seen on https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#CORS-handling

// Also a video from which i got this solution https://youtu.be/ZKEqqIO7n-k

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and any solution worked for me.

The cause was I am using allowRequest to accept or reject the connection using a token I pass in a query parameter.

I have a typo in the query parameter name in the client side, so the connection was always rejected, but the browser complained about cors...

As soon as I fixed the typo, it started working as expected, and I don't need to use anything extra, the global express cors settings is enough.

So, if anything is working for you, and you are using allowRequest, check that this function is working properly, because the errors it throws shows up as cors errors in the browser. Unless you add there the cors headers manually when you want to reject the connection, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using same version for both socket.io and socket.io-client fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue is faced when the node server stoped.
So, check if your node server working ok.

Then you can use
io.set('origins', 'http://yourdomain.com:PORT_NUMBER');

Answer (score 0):

I used version 2.4.0 of socket.io in easyRTC and used the following code in server_ssl.js which worked for me

```
io = require("socket.io")(webServer, {
  handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent, Host, Authorization",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      "Access-Control-Max-Age":86400
    });
    res.end();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get socket.io app working on Chrome, Safari and other browsers but you still encounter CORS issues in Firefox, and you are using a self-signed certificate, then the problem is that Firefox does not accept self-signed certificates by default, and you have to add an exception by going to Firefox's Preferences > Certificates > View Certificates > Add Exception.

If you don't do this, then Firefox shows the error you posted which is misleading, but deep within its Developer Tools, you will find this error: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT. This indicates that Firefox is not accepting the certificate at all because it is self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
  cors: {
    origin:
      String(process.env.ORIGINS_STRING) === "ALL"
        ? true
        : String(process.env.ORIGINS_STRING).split(","),
    methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"],
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "X-Requested-With",
      "X-Access-Token",
      "Content-Type",
      "Host",
      "Accept",
      "Connection",
      "Cache-Control",
    ],
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  },
};
```

in .env file :

```
ORIGINS_STRING=ALL
```

or

```
ORIGINS_STRING=http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:8081
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with `socket.io: 4.2.x`, `node: 14.17.x` & `@hapi/hapi: 20.1.x`.

After trying multiple ways as mentioned in other answers, I found that the only working solutions for these version is:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server.listener, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
```

Please make sure you have `{ cors: { origin: '*' } }` in the options object.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SocketIO with implicit http server and I am using v4.4 of socket io, I had to do it like this in the server:

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server(PORT, {})
io.engine.on("headers", (headers, req) => {
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://yourdomain.com"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methodsn"] = "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply do this in your socketio requiring:-

```
const io = require("socket.io")(8000, {
     cors: {
        origin: "*",
     },
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps to solve my CORS policy issue.