# Cross origin request blocked Pubnub

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, pubnub

I am making a chat app and i am getting these errors (quite a few of them) Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
 The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ps1.pubnub.com/subscribe/sub-c-43a257e0-d94a-11e4-a2b8-0619f8945a4f/my_channel%2Cmy_channel_resent/0/0?uuid=%20User%20Spyros%20with%20number%2080%20has%20come%20online%20&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F3.6.7. (Reason: CORS request failed).

I literally do not know what to do, any ideas??

Comment: Most likely something is up with the headers you're sending

Comment: @NuGnojMik if you could be a little more specific.. :)

Comment: What headers are you sending?

Comment: I am using pubnub and this happens (except from the other times- atleast for this i know when it is getting throwed), when i try to unsubscribe from a channel

Answer (score 2):

PubNub does support CORS.

Are you on Firefox?
Some people see the issue on FF when running a local server, but rebooting the browser often solves the case.

See:
[Firefox CORS request giving 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' despite headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cors-request-giving-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers)

Answer (score 0):

On PubNub’s network, the way data is sent and received on long-lived TCP socket connections, but with a browser, they expect to have special headers, otherwise known as CORS headers to allow certain resources over that connection. If a CORS header is excluded from the payload on a response, an error is thrown in the browser.

These occur when a TCP socket is severed through the browser. Essentially what’s occurring is that the browser notices that it’s missing a CORS header, so no data is coming down the pipe. What really should be happening is the browser should give a TCP socket error saying ‘severed’ or ‘aborted’, but it’s been implemented to deliver a CORS error.

What you really want to look out for is data loss, and if you are, please contact support@pubnub.com!

Comment: I have found, i think, data loss (what i checked was how many data leave the one peer and how many data arrive on the other peer). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you please message us on support@pubnub.com so we can look at this in detail?