# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - How to get around it without having access to the server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am creating a customized homepage, which requires me to get data from various sites (for example, the weather).

I have been using the following code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open('GET', 'http://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/...')
req.send()
req.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log(this.responseText)
})
```

I also tried `req.withCredentials = true` before sending it, but it made no difference.

I found various questions regarding this, however with most of these the users had access to the server. The only one I could find without that was:

[Firefox CORS request giving 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' despite headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371734/5620297)

None of the answers said how to get around the problem, so my question is - **How can I get around this error?**

Comment: You can't.  If you could, you would have identified a very serious security problem. If you cannot change the server, your only choice is to proxy from your *own* server.

Comment: @Pointy Do you know any way for me to set this up. I have XAMPP installed. I was wondering because I would be able to do it using a Firefox Add-on, just open a background tab and load the page. So, I though maybe you could simulate a browser when getting the website data somehow.....

Comment: If you're running XAMPP, just do the ajax request to your own PHP server, and use PHP, which isn't subject to the same-origin policy, to do the request, and pass the result back to the ajax request.

Comment: @adeneo Good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using jsonp

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/SS7:4:UK',
   dataType: 'JSONP',
   jsonpCallback: 'callback',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
}
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: If the server does not honor JSONP requests already, then this will not work.

Comment: Yes, I keep getting the error, no matter what I try: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`