# Access-Control-Allow-Origin htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain

I am trying to enable HTTP access control (CORS) on a site using a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "Content-Type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
```

But I keep getting the error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [DOMAINNAME] (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'Content-Type').

What am I doing wrong? Every tutorial I've found seems to suggest it should work.

-edit-
In Chrome the debug tools give me this additional info:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'Content-Type'.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cors-request-giving-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers). Seems to be a security certificate issue.

Comment: @thickguru there is no security certificate on the site

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
```

Comment: @thickguru Changing the second line from Access-Control-Allow-Origin to Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Success! Thanks so much.

Comment: Ah, everything just blurred into one! My mistake.