# Cors issues with JWT Authentication for WP REST API and local React project

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, jwt, fetch

I succesfully installed "JWT Authentication for WP REST API" and followed (and reviewed multiple times) the instructions for setup correctly.

My React app does authenticate via the **/jwt-auth/v1/token**-endpoint.

I get a token back and store this in my localStorage.

All of my API-calls get added an authorization header as follows from this point on:
`Authorization: Bearer mYCust0mToken`

In the browser, this triggers preflight requests to the server (which is a remote one), that all fail. Basically logging in kills all of my API-requests.

I'm now getting 405's stating the following:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://mywebpage.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I run WP inside a subdir, so I have two .htaccess files, one in the root, one in the wp/-directory. I've tried putting the suggested .htaccess-changes of the [descriptions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) in both files, on several positions of the file, but still no luck.

I've also tried setting Allow-Origin headers to **"*"**, just for the sake of testing. I did that in both the .htaccess-files, but also in my PHP.

Anyone out there that got "JWT Authentication for WP REST API" up and running and willing to tell how?

Comment: Have you tried the specific rules in the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330347/access-control-allow-origin-htaccess-file-not-working/38332030?