# Angular Post Request 404 on Firefox

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm getting 404 error in the console when I try to send a $http.post to a php file.
I have added these 2 lines in the php file, but it still doesn't work. The Post request works fine in Chrome.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: Could be a bad certificate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cors-request-giving-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can try a firefox extension like [Rest Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/)