# CORS Header missing in Firefox although add_header is used

Tags: nginx, loopbackjs, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application that consists of back end and front end. Because of restrictions with the hoster, I need to provide the back end from a different server than the front end.

My back end handles authentication and serves the content to the front end. It also sends emails to users via nodemailer. Because I am not allowed have outgoing TCP sockets on the server where the front end is hosted, this feature failed which made me relocate the back end.

Now, I have the back end running on a different server. It consists of a loopback instance listening on a certain port which gets requests proxied to it by nginx.

After a while of set up, I had the configuration working. It first failed because of a wrong CORS header, a problem that emerged because Loopback added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;`, which I also had in my nginx config. That resulted in Firefox throwing an error like `CORS header does not match Origin (*, *)` - which made me think that the headers where on top of each other thus negating the wildcard `*`.

So I removed the `add_header` part from my nginx configuration. I worked fine when I tested, but when I came back, Firefox threw the Error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://{{my_nice_api}}/lang. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.`. Which baffled me because I hadn't changed the set up at all.

Now, I fiddled even more but am not able to find the error. I have `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` set (for testing purposes obviously), but I keep getting the error that there is no such header present. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers) had me thinking that I needed to add another header in `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;`, but to no avail. Can anybody give any pointer as to what I am missing?

My nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/certs/key.pem;   

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My site.conf (mounted into sites-available):

```
# Virtual Host configuration for {{my_nice_api}}
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name {{my_nice_api}};
    
    return 301 https://{{my_nice_api}}$uri;
    #location / {
    #   rewrite ^ https://{{my_nice_api}}$request_uri permanent;
    #}
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/key.pem;
            
    #server_name {{my_nice_api}};   
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/api/;
            #proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        #proxy_http_version  1.1;
            #proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        #add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be interesting to mention that my set up doesn't run on nginx 1.18, while the (pretty much) same config on nginx 1.14 doesn't have any of the above issues on the server that isn't allowed outgoing tcp

Comment: You should use Fiddler to inspect what exactly is going to/from your nginX.