# Cross origin request (from Angular frontend to Java backend ) blocked

Tags: java, angular, authentication, spring-security, cors

I am writing an app that has a Java Spring back-end (providing an API) and an
Angular front-end.
The Java API works fine through Postman as far as I can see.

But when I try to connect the back-end to the front-end, by launching both
the Java app and the Angular app, going to http://localhost:4200 in a navigator and
fill a form (putting "jseymour@gmail.uk" and "abcdefghi" as password), I get a "Cross Origin Request blocked" error :

Here is the relevant code in my SecurityConfiguration Java class :

```
  @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
```

and the relavant code in my AuthService class :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ClientRegistrationInput} from "../model/input/client-registration-input";
import {LoginInput} from "../model/input/login-input";
import {UtilisateurOutput} from "../model/output/utilisateur-output";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  endpoint: string = 'http://localhost:8000';
  headers = new HttpHeaders(); // .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  currentUser = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router) {
  }
  // Sign-up
  signUp(input: ClientRegistrationInput): Observable<any> {
    let api = `${this.endpoint}/auth/signup-customer`;
    return this.http.post(api, input).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
  // Sign-in
  signIn(loginInput: LoginInput) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.endpoint}/auth/login`, loginInput)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token);
        this.getUserProfile(res.utilisateurId).subscribe((res) => {
          this.currentUser = res;
          this.router.navigate(['user-profile/' + res.utilisateurId]);
        });
      });
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  }
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    return authToken !== null;
  }
  // User profile
  getUserProfile(id: any): Observable<UtilisateurOutput> {
    let api = `${this.endpoint}/utilisateurs/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<UtilisateurOutput>(api, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        return res || {};
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  doLogout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    this.router.navigate(['log-in']);

  }

  // Error handling
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let msg = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      msg = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // server-side error
      msg = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError( () => new Error(msg));
  }
}
```

The error message in Google Chrome :

[image]

The error message in Firefox :

[image]

Source code for Java back-end at https://github.com/ewan-delanoy/ApiPlages
Source code for Angular front-end at https://github.com/ewan-delanoy/FrontEndPlages

Some notes on similar, older MSE questions :

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers)
is about a Firefox-specific problem, while my problem appears in Chrome also.
[This other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe?rq=1)
contains a lot of information and suggestions, in particular :

1. Using a CORS proxy - I want to avoid that since I have full control over both backend and frontend.
2. Being careful about the request & response format to avoid preflight. I may well have missed something
   but it seems to me that the code snippets I showed above do what needs to be done in this regard.

Comment: I noticed there has been a close vote on this question with the explanation "this question includes multiple questions in one". How so ? I have a specific error message and I'm asking for how to fix it. I fail to see those "multiple questions"

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200"); // Add more origins if needed
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can use nginx to solve cross domain problem

Comment: This new code did not solve my problem, but at least it changed the error message, thx

Comment: What is the new error message?

Comment: The new error message in my Java back-end is : MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0. In my debugger I see that most of the request or response is empty

Comment: Token is not generated correctly or not formatted. Maybe you can check token generation in backend.

Answer (score 0):

Add @CrossOrigin("*") on the top of your controller

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It did not help though, the problem stayed the same