# SAP Spartacus CORS issue in Firefox private mode

Tags: cors, spartacus-storefront

In Firefox's private mode, I've encountered a CORS issue when accessing the basesite API URL
CORS:

```
.../occ/v2/basesites?fields=baseSites(uid,defaultLanguage(isocode),urlEncodingAttributes,urlPatterns,stores(currencies(isocode),defaultCurrency(isocode),languages(isocode),defaultLanguage(isocode)),theme,defaultPreviewCatalogId,defaultPreviewCategoryCode,defaultPreviewProductCode)&lang=en&curr=USD
```

Tracking protection ON:
[image]

In our code we just call the OOTB method for to get the basesite data.

```
protected resolveConfig(): Observable<SiteContextConfig> {
    return this.baseSiteService.getAll().pipe(
    .........
}
```

However, upon disabling tracking protection, CORS issues cease to occur, and the site loads successfully.

[image]

Is this an anticipated behavior, or is there a solution to address it?
Your guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Most likely a problem with your certificate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' despite headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371734/firefox-cross-origin-request-blocked-despite-headers)

Comment: @jub0bs i have try adding a preflight but it does not work.

Comment: What does "adding a preflight" mean?