# socket.io, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cors

I have set up a node server with socket io turning and trying to connect to it through another server.
However some browsers on different computers give me this error and makes it reconnect the whole time:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://serverDomain.net:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lo_SdiU. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://www.differentServerDomain.fr' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

my js config:

```
var port = 3000;
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/devpeter.net/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/devpeter.net/fullchain.pem')
};
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.origins('https://www.differentServerDomain.fr:* https://www.differentServerDomain.fr/wp-admin/index.php:*');

// start of server
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *: '+ port + "\n");
});
```

I am using node 8.0 and socket io 2.2,
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
here is the client code:

```
<script src="https://serverDomain.net:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   var socket = io('https://serverDomain.net:3000');
</script>
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I have found a solution.
for some reason the default transportation method is not always allowed by all servers.

So i specified a neutral transportation method at the client side, like this:

```
var socket = io('https://yourDomain:3000', { transports : ['websocket'] });
```

Comment: `transport` did not work for me, `transports` did. I am using socket.io-client 3.1.2

Comment: This will disable HTTP long-polling transport which is not recommended by socket-io documentation for practical reasons. More information is available [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/how-it-works/#upgrade-mechanism)

Comment: Finally found it. even official socket.io doc handle cors did not helped https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 45):

This worked for me

```
var socket = io('http://yourDomain:port', { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: This one worked for me 2 , thank

Comment: same here!
client: socket.io v4 webpacked on Chrome / 
server: express v4

Answer (score 25):

For users of **Socekt io v3**

You need to use option `credentials` in `cors` options of server config.

Example:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(strapi.server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Docs:

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Related topic:

[Socket.io + Node.js Cross-Origin Request Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked)

Migration guide

https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/index.html#CORS-handling

Comment: It worked for me. I really appreciate it, Daniel.

Answer (score 13):

In Client code add this, I got error "NO Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present". so added this on client side.

```js
var connectionOptions =  {
            "force new connection" : true,
            "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
            "timeout" : 10000,                  
            "transports" : ["websocket"]
        };

        this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000',connectionOptions);
```

Answer (score 8):

I recently faced the same issue and the solution that worked for me was the following:

//in the React project install socket.io-client and then

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'   

var socket = io('http://localhost:<your_port_number>', {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
```

Comment: tried lots and lots finally this code helped thank you very much

Comment: Your very welcome @samita :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify the following on the client-side.

`const socket = io('https://yourDomain:3000', { transports: ['websocket'] });`

instead of `const socket = io('https://yourDomain:3000');`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this modification will help you.

```
    var port = 3000;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var https = require('https');
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.differentServerDomain.fr https://www.differentServerDomain.fr");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });


    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/devpeter.net/privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/devpeter.net/fullchain.pem')
    };
    var server = https.createServer(options, app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    // start of server
    server.listen(port, function(){
        console.log('listening on *: '+ port + "\n");
    });
```

Comment: didn't chnage anything, keeps disconnecting reconecting with the same  XMLHttpRequest error. thank you for trying.

Answer (score 1):

Also please check server-side log having this msg "**info  - unhandled socket.io url**" or not. if shown, please upgrade your **socket.io** version to **1.0+**. I solved it by this approach.

**npm install socket.io@1.0**

or change package.json like that:

```
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^1.0"
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer licaomeng, but i have a few functions relying on the 2.0+ version of socket io. in any case, explicitly declaring the transportation method of the protocal to websocket  did it for me (see the accepted answer).