# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, socket.io, directory-structure

I have the following folder structure **html** directory: i**ndex.html, index.html**, **public/js** directory: **main.js, socket.js**, and in the root directory I have **server.js**

In server.js I set up the socket.io as follows :

```
/*********************  WEBSOKETS ***************************/

    const io = require('socket.io')(https);

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('a user connected');
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });
    });

    /************************************************ ***/

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
            console.log('message: ' + msg);
            io.emit('chat message', msg);
        });
    });
```

and in the socket.js file I handle the client part of it:

```
(function ($) {
    var socket = io().connect() // connect to the server

    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            var happyEmoji = $('#messages').html().replace(/(\:\))/g, '&#x1F600;');
            $('#messages').html(happyEmoji);
            var sadEmoji = $('#messages').html().replace(/(\:\()/g, '&#x1F614;');
            $('#messages').html(sadEmoji);
        });
    });
```

})(jQuery);

but then I get the :

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io

I also tried to place directly in my **main.html** file but I get the same error. I think it is because **main.html** is in the **html d**irectory and does not has the direct access to **io** in **server.js** this way.

How to solve it?

Comment: Looks like a scope issue. Is that the whole server.js?  If that's inside curly braces, then the scope of io is limited to that block and not visible in the socket.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert this line to the main.html file:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

This sets your `io` variable, so you can use it:

```
var socket = io();
```

More information and examples [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Answer (score 0):

For new people that might run into this error.

1. After you've inserted this line below in your main.html file

`<script defer src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

or

`<script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

2. And you've set your `io` variable, you also want to specified a neutral transportation method at the client side as shown below

`const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", { transports: ["websocket"] });`

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680738), the default transportation method is not always allowed by all servers.

Reference this for original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680738)