# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'... Socket.io, NodeJs, ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm new to **socket.io**. I have following code in my NodeJs/Express server

```
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('New client connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
    socket.emit('FromAPI', 'hello');
});
//My port here is 8848
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    logger.log('info', `Server started at :${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

And following code in **Client React app** and my react app is hosted in port 3000 as http://localhost:3000

```
import socketIO from 'socket.io-client';
componentDidMount() {
    const endPoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8848';
    const socket = socketIO(endPoint);
    socket.on('FromAPI', data => console.log(data));

  }
```

With this code i got the following error on the browser console:

> polling-xhr.js:263 GET http://127.0.0.1:8848/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MMT-4kl 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>   Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8848/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MMT-Aso: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Anyone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Do you have a CORS extension in your browser. If yes turn that on. If not use this chrome extension and try. [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en]

Comment: you need to respond with the correct (calling) host as the value of `access-control-allow-origin` - though to be honest, I can't see where your CORS headers are being sent from anyway

Comment: @anjuc - that is extremely poor and dangerous advice

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN Web Doc , you can add the host urls.

**solution 1**

There is probably similar question answered already. If that does not work for you try solution 2.

Here is the stackoverflow answer : [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628363/socket-io-access-control-allow-origin-error?rq=1)

**Solution 2**

> Limiting the possible Access-Control-Allow-Origin values to a set of allowed origins requires code on the server side to check the value of the Origin request header, compare that to a list of allowed origins, and then if the Origin value is in the list, to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value to the same value as the Origin value.
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://abc.xyz.gi

so in your case

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost

or

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://127.0.0.1

Further relevant QA [read more on stackeoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1)