# Socket.io-client is not connecting to socket.io server react and node(express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I try to connect to a socket.io-client using the following code:

client:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket;

const Chat = ({location}) => {

const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
const EP = 'http://localhost:5000/';

useEffect(() =>{
    const {name , room} = queryString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(EP);

    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    console.log(socket);
},[EP, location.search])

return(
    <h1>helloooooooooooooo {name} welcome to {room}</h1>
)
}

export default Chat;
```

server:

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const router = require('./router/router');

const PORT = process.env.PORT ||5050;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);




//socket.io

io.on('connection', socket => {
console.log("we have a new user!!!!!!!!!");

socket.on('disconnect', () =>{
    console.log('User had left!');
})
})

// io.on('connection', socket => { 
//     console.log("we have a new user!!!!!!!!");

//     socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("user is left"))        
//  });

app.use(router);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server has started on ${PORT}`));
```

i dont get connet or disconnect console log from this server socket.
i follow same process as socke.io doc.

[console message from browser, its showing disconnected true and connected false and no id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t6BV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in client, inside useEffect instead of

```
socket = io(EP);
```

to this

```
socket = io.connect(EP , {
        "force new connection" : true,
        "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
        "timeout" : 10000,                  
        "transports" : ["websocket"],
        withCredentials:true,
            extraHeaders:{
                "my-custom-header": "abcd"
            }
    });
```

[i got this solution from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628363/socket-io-access-control-allow-origin-error/65188436#65188436)

Answer (score 1):

Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

```
// server-side
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// client-side
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("https://api.example.com", {
  withCredentials: true,
  extraHeaders: {
    "my-custom-header": "abcd"
  }
});
```

Comment: thank u so much, i try it many way and i read socket doc carefully, but unfortunately still didnt work.
still not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, the WebSocket object does not support additional headers. In case you want to add some headers as part of some authentication mechanism, you can use the `transportOptions` attribute. Please note that in this case the headers won't be sent in the WebSocket upgrade request.

```
 // WILL NOT WORK in the browser
    const socket = new Socket('http://localhost', {
      extraHeaders: {
        'X-Custom-Header-For-My-Project': 'will not be sent'
      }
    });
    // WILL NOT WORK
    const socket = new Socket('http://localhost', {
      transports: ['websocket'], // polling is disabled
      transportOptions: {
        polling: {
          extraHeaders: {
            'X-Custom-Header-For-My-Project': 'will not be sent'
          }
        }
      }
    });
    // WILL WORK
    const socket = new Socket('http://localhost', {
      transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
      transportOptions: {
        polling: {
          extraHeaders: {
            'X-Custom-Header-For-My-Project': 'will be used'
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Credit: [Engine.IO client](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#nodejs-with-extraheaders)