# Cors policy in socketio express

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors

I am getting following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NWrnTy1' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

my node server code:

```
//import express from "express";
//import http from "http";

const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", () => {
    console.log("Connected!");
});

var redis = require('redis');  
var url = "redis://localhost:6379"  
var client = redis.createClient(url);  

client.on('message', function(channel, msg) {  
  io.sockets.emit(msg);
});

client.subscribe('JoinCall');


server.listen(8001);
```

my index.html on apache:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
  //var socket = io();
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001');
  sock.on('twits', function(msg) {
    console.log('message received: '+msg);//Do something with message here.
  });

</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628363/socket-io-access-control-allow-origin-error transports did the trick

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628363/socket-io-access-control-allow-origin-error answer to this question solved the problem. use transports

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628363/socket-io-access-control-allow-origin-error answer helped me.. use transports

Comment: did you know you can do `io.connect(':8001')`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had ton of problems with CORS and they were all resolved by installing the npm package cors and let it do this job. I would suggest to remove your manual setting headers and try this instead. Saved my life.

Install the cors package by running 'npm i cors'. Then in your server file add these:

```
const cors = require('cors');

// Add these lines above any route / mounting
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Answer (score -1):

in socket.io client I used a neutral transport layer:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8001', { transports : ['websocket'] });
```