# socket.io connect failed on production, working in localhost

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, netlify

I have this in server.js

```
//socket io config
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED', ({ notification }) => {
    io.emit(`SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED`, notification)
  })
  //and many more
})
```

In my client (react)

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io('localhost:3001') // working in localhost
```

in my prod I do this checking

```
let socket = io('localhost:3001')
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { socket = 
  io('https://api.example.com:3001') 
}
```

Why is it so? I don't think it's cors issue because I already did

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}))
```

my package.json deps

```
"socket.io": "^2.1.1",
"socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
```

Comment: Have you mentioned your port number in port for production?

Comment: const socket = io('http://{your machine's ip}:4001')

Comment: @SantoshShinde yeah that's what I did. Do I have to setup reverse proxy or anything like that in node.js?

Comment: Can you add package.json of your client(react) ?

Comment: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1413

Comment: @SantoshShinde but I'm using create-react-app

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To know which route you should point in the api, access to the address "**/socket.io/**". For example, if you are runing on localhost:3001 should be "**http://localhost:3001/socket.io/**" and the response

```
{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

Be sure you are declaring the same server name and route in production. If you use a kind of proxy or sub route like /api you have to add it. This is an example.

*SERVER ROUTE DECLARATION*

```
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = {
    path: "/api/socket.io",
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
};
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);

io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    socket.on('SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED', ({ notification }) => {
        io.emit(`SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED`, notification)
    })
});
```

*CLIENT DECLARATION LISTENER (FOR REACT HOOKS)*

```
  let socket = io("https://www.yoursite.com", { path: '/api/socket.io/' });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED', function (data) {
      console.log(`RECEIVED`);
    });
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your server code please add the following line

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

So your code will be

```
  //socket io config
  const server = require('http').createServer(app)
  const io = require('socket.io')(server)
  io.set('origins', '*:*');
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED', ({ notification }) => {
      io.emit(`SOCKET_COMMENT_RECEIVED`, notification)
    })
    //and many more
  })
```

For more help to follow [this](https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/react/react-socket-io-tutorial/) tutorial & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked) question.

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/TutorialEdge/react-typescript-real-time-chat).

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Why `io.set('origins', '*:*')` is different from `app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}))` ??

Comment: same error I got. In firefox I see this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallow`

Comment: Can you please just use app.use(cors())

Comment: the strange part is I have no issue running it on local, have you tried to publish ur repo to production?

Comment: Yes it's working but I simply use cors without extra config

Comment: tried bunch of things, nothing worked, not sure it's my ssl issue.

Comment: Maybe, do you have repo then give me access or just try with demo on production

Comment: I deployed your code https://github.com/TutorialEdge/react-typescript-real-time-chat with netlify, having the exact same problem with mine, do you familiar with netlify? I don't think it's code level issue now.

Comment: Okay Can you please share that url with me ?

Comment: sure. https://mystifying-fermat-004141.netlify.com/ in chrome the error message is different than in firefox, in firefox the error msg is cros related.

Comment: Have you update the code io.set('origins', '*:*'); ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked

Comment: I did not touch your code, it is there: https://github.com/TutorialEdge/react-typescript-real-time-chat/blob/master/backend/src/app.ts#L9. I really suspect something is wrong with netlify, it has't been so hard with cors issue, previously I have no problem setup socket.io with reverse proxy in nginx.

Comment: Actually this is not my repo I just shared sample which I have referred for me, and you have to update the code which I have mentied in my answer

Comment: What else I need to do? You said `io.set('origins', '*:*');` which is already here https://github.com/TutorialEdge/react-typescript-real-time-chat/blob/master/backend/src/app.ts#L9

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with CORS- it was a problem with the security certificate.

Comment: You mean the SSL? previously I also have SSL but I didn't do extra step to make it work, the only different is previously I host my client using nginx reverse proxy, this time I try netlify.

Comment: Maybe you're right because in my localhost it doesn't use ssl.