# Socket.IO: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: ssl, firefox, socket.io, cors

I have a strange issue in FF which is not reproduced in Chrome: websocket connection to another origin does not work when using SSL connection.

My Rails app is running on `https://wax.lvh.me:3000` and socket.io node JS app is running on `https://wax.lvh.me:3001`. When I try to connect to the socket from the Rails app in FF I see the following warnings in the browser's dev console:

[image]

When I open the Network tab I see the following response headers - notice that there are no access-control headers in the response:

[image]
I tried to use the following recipes from the others SO answers:

Set up origins to `'*:*'` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749535/3676469)

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Set up origins to a function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081944/3676469)

```
io.origins (origin, callback) =>
  if origin.match(/lvh\.me/)
    return callback(null, true)

  callback('Origin not allowed', false)
```

But nothing helped me to fix this issue so far

Notice that access-control headers are set correctly in Chrome:

[image]

I use the following browser and tool versions:

- Firefox - 63.0.3 (64-bit)
- Google Chrome - Version 73.0.3683.39 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
- Socket.io - 2.2.0

Do you have any ideas how to set up CORS in socket.io for FF correctly?

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAcdu.png doesn’t show the response headers — it only shows the request headers. You need to instead look at the Response tab there.

Comment: @sideshowbarker the Response is blank

Comment: try to set the `origins` ( on the server ) using `io.origins('*:*')` and on the client side : `socket = io.connect('https://wax.lvh.me:3000', { transports: ['websocket'] });`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was everything OK with CORS configuration in our socket.io app

The problem was with SSL certificates: our configuration was missing `ca` (intermediate certificate) option in the HTTPS server initialization. We fixed the issue with this code:

```
require('https').createServer({
  ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CA),         // this config was missing
  cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERT),
  key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY)
})
```

As [nodeJS create Secure Context documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) says:

> ca `string` | `string[]` | `Buffer` | `Buffer[]`. Optionally override the trusted CA certificates. Default is to trust the well-known CAs curated by Mozilla. Mozilla's CAs are completely replaced when CAs are explicitly specified using this option. The value can be a string or Buffer, or an Array of strings and/or Buffers. Any string or Buffer can contain multiple PEM CAs concatenated together. The peer's certificate must be chainable to a CA trusted by the server for the connection to be authenticated. When using certificates that are not chainable to a well-known CA, the certificate's CA must be explicitly specified as a trusted or the connection will fail to authenticate. If the peer uses a certificate that doesn't match or chain to one of the default CAs, use the ca option to provide a CA certificate that the peer's certificate can match or chain to. For self-signed certificates, the certificate is its own CA, and must be provided. For PEM encoded certificates, supported types are "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE", "X509 CERTIFICATE", and "CERTIFICATE".