# Socket.io cors error by using node, react and socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

We are using CORS to allow all origins

```
app.use(cors());
```

server running on port 4000, and client running on 3000

here is my **server.js** code

```
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || process.env.DEFAULT_PORT;
console.log("port: ", port);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at ${port}...`);
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new socketIO(server, {
  transports: ["websocket"],

});
```

React js code

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    try {
      this.socket = io("http://localhost:4000", { transport: ["websocket"] });

      this.socket.on("Chat-event", data => {
        console.log("socketdata", data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("hiterror", error)
    }
  }
```

I am continuously getting this error on the client side after allowing origin for all.

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mv-SSIc' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute**

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked

Comment: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 5):

For socket.io version 3.x.x cors configuration has changed, I managed to fix it by adding options to the socket creation.
Tried on the version 2.x.x also and it worked.

```
  const io = socketio(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Here is the resource https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

**Bonus**: In case you encounter **Bad Request** make sure you have the same version of socket.io for the client and the server.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer gave me solution.

Comment: This worked for me, My client side package.json was "socket.io-client":^2.4.0 while my backend package.json was  "socket.io": ^4.4.0. I npm uninstalled socket.io-client from client and then re installed with npm install socket.io-client@4.4.0 and my websocket connected

Answer (score 1):

By following these steps you can get rid of these error.

```
// 1) on server side

const cors = require('cors');
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketio(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: localhost:3000/, //your website origin
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

// 2) add these middlewares
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors());

// 3) on client-side
import io from 'socket.io-client'
let socket = io.connect(localhost:8080, { transports: ['websocket'] }) // your local server
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the cors credentials config:

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true}));
```

Comment: didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Please allow all to `socket.io` at server side

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});
```

Or you can set socketIO origins as `*`

```
socketIO.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference , remember I am using socket.io version 2.2.0 for both client and server

Comment: have you checked your .htaccess file? maybe its help you

Comment: from where i can access this ?

Comment: Please check in your server >> app and add
`Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"`

Answer (score 0):

@user4860402 Gave me solution, thing is that by default npm is installing socket.io client v 2.X.X but on server I'm using latest verion (also provided by npm) 3.0.5
So all problems including 400 error comes because client and server verion doesnot match.

Answer (score -1):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");
const io = socketio(http, {cors:{origin:"*"}});
```