# Socket.IO - has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: socket.io, cors

I am using SocketIO to create a web chat application.

When I work locally everything is fine, but when I release it to our live domain I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://example.com:2096/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1586507948354-0'
>   from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Here is how I connect from the client to the server:

```
var socket = io(document.domain + ':' + supPort, {secure: true});
```

I have researched and I was advised to put this into the virtual host config file of the domain in Apache2:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

However the error is still the same.

Why am I receiving this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: If the server is written in Node JS, in the server write `io.set('origins', '*:*');` as per answered question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked