# Getting a CORS error when trying to establish socket.io connection between back-end on localhost:3000 and front-end on localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to figure out how to create a real time chat application that uses Vue.js for the front-end, Node.js for the back-end and socket.io.

I've generated my back-end Node.js project with express-generator and the project is accessible at http://localhost:3000. In this project I have an index.js file that contains this:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').createServer(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

My front-end is a Vue.js project accessible from http://localhost:8080 and the component that is meant to connect to my back-end contains this:

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        Hello
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import socket from 'socket.io-client'

export default {
    mounted(){
        socket.connect('http://localhost:3000')
    }
}

</script>
```

Sadly the socket connection doesn't seem to go through. On the front-end console I get these errors -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6JFKSo' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polling-xhr.js?d33e:268 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6JFKSo net::ERR_FAILED
```

And on the back-end console I get errors like this one - `GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6JFrfo 404 5.289 ms - 975`

I can't figure out why is this happening.

Comment: Have you enabled cors on the backend service?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

Comment: On your node js server add the cors module. 

// npm install --save cors

and then add this to your code :

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

Comment: I did that but nothing changed. I'm surely doing something wrong since I just recently started using Node.js instead of Laravel but I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

In `index.js`, add the following line below your important for socket.io:

```
io.origins('localhost:8080')
```

or if you want it for any domain:

```
io.origins('*:*')
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked)

Comment: I did tried the solutions on the question you linked but they didn't work for me and still don't.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried setting the headers like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54309080/8993539