# Sending data from the client to the server and displaying to the terminal using `sockets`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

On the client side, it calls `socket.current.emit` in `useEffect`. I am trying to send the name and age to the server and display the data in the server side `io.on` terminal. I have no error, nothing is displayed in the terminal.

**BACKEND**

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`connect on the port ${port} - ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
});

const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('hello', data => {
      console.log({name: data.name, age: data.age});
    });
});
```

**FRONTEND**

**client**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';


const ChatUser = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        chatters: [],
        idReceiver: '',
        idSender: ''
    });

    const [activeUser, setActiveUser] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

    const socket = useRef();
    

    useEffect(() => {

        if(!socket.current) {
            socket.current = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API);
        }

        if(socket.current) {
            socket.current.emit('hello', {name: 'john', age: '23'});
        }
    }, []);


    return (
        <>  

        </>
    );
};

//env
REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:8000/api
```

**Updated backend**

My code in server.js Maybe I should put `io.on` in different place?

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const db = require('./connection');
const app = express();


// Connect to our Database and handle an bad connections
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        autoIndex: false
    })
    .then(() => console.log("DB server connect"))
    .catch(() => console.log("DB server disconnect"))


const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/message');
const countriesRoutes = require('./routes/countries');
const languagesRoutes = require('./routes/languages');
const tutorRoutes = require('./routes/tutor');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Content-Type: application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*'); 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Allow','GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    req.io = io;
    next();
});

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

    app.use(cors());

}

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`connect on the port ${port} - ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
});


const io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
});


io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('hello', data => {
      console.log({name: data.name, age: data.age});
    });
});


//middleware
app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', countriesRoutes);
app.use('/api', languagesRoutes);
app.use('/api', tutorRoutes);
app.use('/api', messageRoutes);
```

**Request header**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
```

**404 not found - in terminal**

`GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NtFERz- 404`

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors on browser console? I tested you code and I see CORS error on browser. If you can confirm that you are also getting this error on browser then this answer should help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749535/6338245

Comment: @FahadFarooq I added my full code in file server.js. Maybe I should put `io.on` in different place or change order functions?

Comment: when I run you backend code I get `TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function` on line: `const io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {`. Which version of `socket.io` are you using?

Comment: NVM, The problem here is that you are trying to connect to the wrong url.

Comment: @FahadFarooq "socket.io-client": "^3.0.5",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not combine the **express** and **socket** correctly to set up the server.

> **Also you can see this video:**
>
> [React and Socket.io with Express in 15 minutes](https://youtu.be/SMubOngCCmw)

**SERVER - BACK-END**

Follow the steps below:

1. The Built-in HTTP Module

   - Node.js has a built-in module called HTTP, which allows Node.js to transfer data over the Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP). The HTTP module can create an HTTP server that listens to server ports and gives a response back to the client.
   - Use the `createServer()` method to create an HTTP server:

```js
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
```

2. Create a utility file with a custom name, here is the name of this `socketUtils.js` :

   - Here we set up the socket with custom configs, and instantiate.

```js
// <root-project-dir>/utils/socketUtils.js

const socketIO = require("socket.io");

exports.sio = (server) => {
  return socketIO(server, {
    transports: ["polling"],
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
    },
  });
};

exports.connection = (io) => {
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user is connected");

    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      console.log(`message from ${socket.id} : ${message}`);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(`socket ${socket.id} disconnected`);
    });
  });
};
```

3. Well now it's time to use the `socketUtils.js` file:

```js
const http = require("http");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");

dotenv.config({
  path: "./config.env",
});

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socketUtils = require("./utils/socketUtils");

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketUtils.sio(server);
socketUtils.connection(io);
```

4. Create a socket middleware:

   - To access the socket globally in each request, we create a middleware.

```js
const socketIOMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.io = io;

  next();
};
```

5. Use the `listen()` method:

   - You can write other middleware according to the priority that exists with the routes you need and then put the `listen()` method at the end.

```js
// CORS
app.use(cors());

// ROUTES
app.use("/api/v1/hello", socketIOMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  req.io.emit("message", `Hello, ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.send("hello world!");
});

// LISTEN
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

**The final file should look like this:**

```js
// <root-project-dir>/index.js

const http = require("http");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");

dotenv.config({
  path: "./config.env",
});

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socketUtils = require("./utils/socketUtils");

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketUtils.sio(server);
socketUtils.connection(io);

const socketIOMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.io = io;

  next();
};

// CORS
app.use(cors());

// ROUTES
app.use("/api/v1/hello", socketIOMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  req.io.emit("message", `Hello, ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.send("hello world!");
});

// LISTEN
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

> Finally, to test the server, you can use [**SocketIO Client Tool**](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/)
> online tool, which is very useful.

---

**CLIENT - FRONT-END**

After setting up the server, you can use it as follows in the React app and emit an event:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  const socket = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("ws://localhost:9013");

    socket.current.on("connnection", () => {
      console.log("connected to server");
    });
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    socket.current.emit("message", new Date().getTime());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Socket.io app</p>

      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Emit a time message
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> **Finally, you can access the source code in GitHub repo via the link below:**
> https://github.com/mohammadoftadeh/simple-react-socket-io

Comment: It doesn't work form me. I see in tab " network" in dev tools browser "Request URL: http://localhost:8900/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ntie-9O "   it is red color

Comment: @Umbro. It's work correctly, You definitely did some parts wrong, because it has been tested and everything works perfectly in the video tutorial I linked to. https://youtu.be/SMubOngCCmw

Comment: Can you put your code on https://stackblitz.com/. Online code editor?

Comment: @Umbro. You can access the source code in GitHub repo via the link below: https://github.com/mohammadoftadeh/simple-react-socket-io

Comment: But your file `client` in Github isn't configurate

Comment: @Umbro. I added the client in GitHub. You can check again. Everything is working great, Sorry, I do not know why I think you are looking for an excuse. https://github.com/mohammadoftadeh/simple-react-socket-io/tree/main/react-client

Answer (score 0):

Change `REACT_APP_API` env variable from `http://localhost:8000/api` to `http://localhost:8000` i.e. remove the `/api`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I run app in browser using url: http://localhost:3000, server port 8000.. Maybe my variable in `env` I should change to; REACT_APP_API env variable from http://localhost:3000  ??

Comment: I have your code running on my system without any problem after this change, though I am on socket-io version 4. I'll check on your version. Meanwhile, can you attach a SS of your request headers from network tab. Request headers for any one of the requests that start with `/socket.io/?`.

Comment: Same with your version, no issues. Can you attach a Screen Shot of your network request. That will give me some clue about the issue.

Comment: Can you try changing `socket.current = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API);` to `socket.current = io("http://localhost:8000");`.

Comment: Updated. I added request header

Answer (score 0):

Use the http package.

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    ....
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    ....
});
```

Comment: I did it, but i can't still see result in terminal

Comment: If you console.log just before the "socket.on" line, do you get a confirmed connection?

Comment: I did in this way: `io.on('connection', function(data) {

  console.log('new client connected');

});`  and I can see 'new client connected` in my terminal

Comment: Yes, I can see `console.log('new client connected');` before `socket.on`