# I got this error when run socket.io in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, socket.io

**Error:**

```
events.js:167
node_app_1  |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event<br>
node_app_1  |       ^
node_app_1  | Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 50.177.55.2:3000<br>
node_app_1  |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1269:19)<br>
node_app_1  |     at listenInCluster (net.js:1334:12)<br>
node_app_1  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1460:7)<br>
node_app_1  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:62:10)<br>
node_app_1  | Emitted 'error' event at:<br>
node_app_1  |     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1313:8)<br>
node_app_1  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)<br>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Change your socker-io server's IP to `127.0.0.1`

---

Your app is trying to listen on port `3000` and I believe it is already being used.

If you have some other service running on this port, you will either have to change the port of your socket-io server or follow the following process to kill the process that is already listening on port 3000.

Type the following in your terminal,

```sh
lsof -i:3000
```

It will show you the process that is listening to that port. Then you can kill that process using its process ID (PID)

```sh
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: thank's for replay but the the port 3000 used only  for this socket.io

Comment: Did you try to kill it and restart your docker container?

Comment: yeah, the same .

Comment: Could you attach the result of the terminal command `sudo lsof -i:3000`?

Comment: You're running `netstat` because `lsof` is not working for you? What is your machine?

Comment: I run it in linux

Comment: Can you show the output of `sudo lsof -i:3000` then?

Comment: `hamza@vps-656a1918:~$ sudo lsof -i:3000
hamza@vps-656a1918:~$`

Comment: return nothing .

Comment: Oh wait, you need to change the IP to `127.0.0.1`. Your current value is `50.177.55.2`

Comment: i used for production env i can't access if i use 127.0.0.1

Comment: It's fine because in production as well you will run a docker container, right? Then it is still going to be `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nc9mV3n. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: Does this comes when you try to connect to the server from a soket-io client?

Comment: You need to allow CORS in your socket-server then. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked). But setting up CORS in your server is a different problem. This is fixed for you now

Comment: ok, i will read it and if is done, i accept your answer