# CORS request did not succeed in EC2 nodeJS application

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have this simple nodejs websocket program running in an EC2 instance

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
io.on("connection", socket => {
console.log("new client connected");
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'));
```

As you can see I am using CORS in my program but When i am connecting from browser i am getting this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ec2-XXXXXX.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NcZV0e-. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

THis is how i am calling it from browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('https://ec2-XXX.compute.amazonaws.com:3000');
        socket.on('connect', (s) => {
        console.log('connected!');
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Have to try to use cors middleware before initializing the socket.io with http server ?

Comment: Above NODEJS program is all i am trying in my EC2

Comment: Try to use app.use(cors()) beofore socket intilization

`
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);
io.on("connection", socket => {
console.log("new client connected");
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'));
`

Comment: still same issue

Comment: So, I think this issue not with nodejs but with the ec2 instance. Has you allowed incoming and outgoing traffic in security group of ec2 ?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked) ?