# IO Is Not Defined - Socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, server, socket.io

I'm currently working on a real-time chat web page. I was originally thinking about using PHP, but am testing out `socket.io` for the backend.

I'm running into a problem where the browser's console logs `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`. I've looked this up many times on this site, as well as others, and most of the answers say to make sure that your `<script>` tag has the `src` pointing to `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` and not just `/socket.io/socket.io.js`. I already have this in my HTML code. Here's a snippet of the code:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <title>Chat</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../libs/fontawesome.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- My code here -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

socket.on("chat-message", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

**server.js**

```js
const io = require("socket.io")(3000);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("chat-message", "Hello World!");
});
```

Basically, all it should do now is that when a user connects to the page, the server sends a request to the client with the `data` of `Hello World!`. The client then just `console.log()` this data.

I'm getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` error in the BROWSER console, and it says the issue is in `script.js` in the first line: `const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");`.

Thank you in advance. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket.io `<script>` tag has a `defer` attribute, meaning it will run after the document has been parsed. This means that it runs after script.js, which is not deferred. To fix this, just add a `defer` attribute to the script.js `<script>` tag, as deferred scripts run in the order they are defined.

Comment: Alright thanks. This changed something. Unfortunately, now I'm getting other errors. I assume they are completely unrelated to the `io is not defined`, but I'd still like to bring them up. The errors: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NuTr5KY' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and `GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NuTrGZE net::ERR_FAILED 200`. Any idea what these mean?

Comment: @IPSDSILVA I'm not entirely familiar with socket.io, but I recommend you take a look at https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked