# Blocked cors of socket.io nodejs when deploy at vercel app

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm using socket.io to make a realtime chat app. Almost all api works except socket.
My console shows
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example-server.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OVLsA1y&sid=GaWraRTVn-d2od-LAAAC' from origin 'https://example.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

this is my code at:
client:

```js
const socket = io("https://example-server.vercel.app", {withCredentials: true,}).connect();
```

server:

```js
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: true,
        credentials: true,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
        exposedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    },
    allowEIO3: true,
});
```

I have tried the ways from the links that have been helped like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

but it not working with me.Thanks for your help!

More information: when i running at localhost it work