# Error in mozilla firefox using socket.io

Tags: node.js, cross-browser, socket.io

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://jsgnr.eshopcomp.com/bwl/wl. (Reason: CORS request failed). <unknown>
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
```

I am getting this kind of error when i am using mozilla works fine in chrome and also i am getting memory leaked error in node console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the server source, you can try to use:

```
io.set('origins', 'http://nameofyourdomain.com:80');
```

Obviously, you need to replace the domain/port with those which are applicable to your setup.

This Stack Overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711242/5070356 has a pretty good breakdown of configuring `origins`