# socket.io client can not communicate to socket server at different port

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am learning **nodejs** event driven programming using `socket.io`, so that I could build a chat app.

So, I created a `Server` and `Client` running at different ports, in `localhost` right now.

### Server at 8080

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {origins: '*.*', transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']});
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Cat Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:%d', port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('Connection to client established ', socket);

    var addedUser = false;

    // when the client emits 'love event', this listens and executes
    socket.on('LoveEvent', function (data) {
        console.log("we tell the client to execute 'logevent'")
        socket.broadcast.emit('LoveEvent', {
            username: socket.username,
            message: data
        });
    });
);
```

### Client at 3000

Client is connecting to server 8080 via socket.io

I have following code in `public/chat.js` which is included in `public/index.html`

```
  var socket = io();
  socket.connect('http://localhost:8080', {transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']})
  console.log("Connection to Cat socket server, ", socket)
```

And, `public/index.html` is

```
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/chat.js"></script>
```

The client structure is

```
$ ll
total 24
-rw-r--r--   1 prayagupd  staff    30 Nov  1 20:18 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 prayagupd  staff   325 Nov  1 20:18 Server.js
drwxr-xr-x  91 prayagupd  staff  3094 Oct 26 18:11 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 prayagupd  staff   249 Nov  1 20:18 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   8 prayagupd  staff   272 Nov  1 20:22 public
```

with `node_modules` having `socket.js`

```
$ ll node_modules/socket.io/lib/
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  staff  5411 Oct 26 15:59 client.js
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  staff  8933 Oct 26 15:59 index.js
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  staff  5366 Oct 26 15:59 namespace.js
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  staff  9493 Oct 26 15:59 socket.js
```

### BUT

When I start my server

```
$ node Server.js 
Cat Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

and Client,

```
$ node Client.js 
Cat client running at localhost:3000
```

I expect a connection message at server-side, as I'm debugging with message in `Server.js` as `console.log('Connection to client established ', socket);`

I manually tried creating `socket` from chorme console and sent an event, the server does not seem to subscribe it.

```
s.connect("http://localhost:8080", {autoConnect : true})
Socket {io: Manager, nsp: "/", json: Socket, ids: 0, acks: Object…}
s.emit("LoveEvent", "Love")
Socket {io: Manager, nsp: "/", json: Socket, ids: 0, acks: Object…}
```

Also, when the client at browser, has following `404 error` on `transport=polling` in browser console,

[image]

I don't know why is it polling on port 3000, which is itself.

It was working well, when everything was in the same server. I refactored it and now :(

I have both backend and frontend code here => [prayagupd/lovejs](https://github.com/prayagupd/lovecat.js)

Answer (score 0):

When the client and the socket.io server are separate, you should download and copy the socket.io client library (`socket.io.js` at https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) in a "socket.io" subfolder of your client app (for instance) and then import it like this:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Or without copying it, you can simply import it from the CDN:

`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>`

(won't work without an internet connection).

And you can remove the socket.io route from the server, which is useless in this case:

`io = require('socket.io')({ serveClient: false, ...});`

Comment: then whats the point of adding dependency `"socket.io" : "^1.5.1" ` in `package.json` ?? Let me see if your idea works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is the format of your origins `*.*`, `*:*` [how to set origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771805/how-to-set-socket-io-origins-to-restrict-connections-to-one-url/21711242#21711242), but socket.io should work even on a different port.

Comment: On my server, I'm using `*.*`, you can see in line `var io = require('socket.io')(http, {origins: '*.*', transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']});
`

Answer (score 0):

this also happened to me,
but I changed from socket.io version **3** to **2** => **"socket.io": "^2.3.0"**
and it solved the problem.

Comment: You can format your answers with `  ` (backticks)