# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - socket.io

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io, cross-domain

There is a node.js service listening on `port:8080` and my asp.net mvc application needs to communicate with node.js service using socket.io

This works fine in local host. But getting 502 and 522 error codes after publishing both mvc and node.js projects in my AWS EC2 instance.

[image: Errors]
**Node.js**

```
 var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var querystring = require('querystring');
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var uniqid = require('uniqid');

    io.set('origins', 'www.mydomain.com:80');
```

Comment: You say port 8080, but `io.set()` shows port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved after adding a firewall inbound rule for port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Read More About [origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771805/how-to-set-socket-io-origins-to-restrict-connections-to-one-url/21711242#21711242)

Comment: @OshadaEkanayake ok try this: io.origins('*:*') ;

Comment: @OshadaEkanayake Please check your firewall settings i think your port not enable.

Comment: I checked the port 8080 with telnet client. but port 8080 is not blocked

Comment: Issue is fixed after adding a firewall inbound rule for port 8080. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @OshadaEkanayake - This is a bit odd because you accepted this answer (perhaps because Gausul did help you), but the answer itself does not describe the actual solution.  It seems that either Gausul should edit the answer to include the actual solution or you should accept your answer which is the solution.  So, if one reads your question and the accepted answer, you don't actually get a correct impression of what the solution to the problem was.  It's not supposed to be that way.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I'm new for stackoverflow. I posted the answer but I can't mark it as correct answer myself

Comment: @OshadaEkanayake - You can accept your own answer after 48 hours.  See: [Can I Answer My Own Question - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).